# javascript for-in loop

Tags: javascript

As the defination says for-in loop is used to loop through the properties of an object ,than why is it looping the element of an array?

```
var arr = ['a','b','c'], indexes = [];

 Array.prototype.each = function() {/*blah*/};

 for (var index in arr) {
  indexes.push(index);
}
indexes; //["0", "1", "2", "each"]
```

why are 0,1,2 enumerated?They are not the properties

Comment: `var index in arr` means that `index` will take on the index on every value in `arr`. To get the value you need to dereference `arr` with `index`. i.e: `arr[index]`

Comment: read this answer: [JavaScript “For …in” with Arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/javascript-for-in-with-arrays)

Comment: *"They are not the properties"* Yes, they are properties. `"1" in arr; // true`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quote from the [`documentation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in):

> for..in should not be used to iterate over an Array where index order
> is important. Array indexes are just enumerable properties with
> integer names and are otherwise identical to general Object
> properties.  There is no guarantee that for...in will return the
> indexes in any particular order and it will return all enumerable
> properties, including those with non–integer names and those that are
> inherited.
>
> Because the order of iteration is implementation dependent, iterating
> over an array may not visit elements in a consistent order. Therefore
> it is better to use a for loop with a numeric index (or Array.forEach
> or the non-standard for...of loop) when iterating over arrays where
> the order of access is important.

The key here holding the answer to your question is the following sentence:

> Array indexes are just enumerable properties with integer names and
> are otherwise identical to general Object properties.

And the following sentence sums it up:

> for..in should not be used to iterate over an Array where index order
> is important.

Comment: if u do arr.length output is only 3 ,this means that properties are not counted right?Only argument.And how can the argument be properties ?

Comment: `arr.length` returns only the number of elements in the array, properties are ignored. But an array could also contain properties. Consider the following code for example: `var arr = [1, 2, 3]; arr.foo = 'bar';`. Now `arr.length` will return 3 but try a for...in loop and you will see the mess it creates. You should not use for...in with arrays. Javascript is a strange beast indeed.

Answer (score 1):

Each index in the array for which the array has an element is a property of that array. So this is basically what your array looks like behind the scenes:

```
>>> arr

    {
        0: 'a',
        1: 'b',
        2: 'c',
        'each': function() {}
        'length': 3
    };
```

These keys are enumerable which is the reason why you're seeing them in your output.

Comment: if u do arr.length output is only 3 ,this means that properties are not counted right?Only argument.And how can the argument be properties ?

Comment: @Maizere No, only the elements that you give the array are counted.

Answer (score 0):

The `for` `in` loop iterates over keys, not values. So it's giving your the array indexes 0, 1, 2 not the values.

You could do it like this but it's bad practice to use a `for in` on an array.

```
for (var index in arr) {
    indexes.push(arr[index]);
}
```

You should use a regular `for` loop

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    indexes.push(arr[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`for...in` interates over the **enumerable** properties of an Object. The enumerable property of `Array` is the index.

More information can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in).

AMCAScript 6 defines the [`for...of` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) which allows iteration over the values. However this has not yet been adopted.

Comment: @Maizere You have to do that by clicking the tick to the left. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you really want to use for in and not use the keys you can make the values into keys like this e.g.:

```
var arr = {'a':1,'b':1,'c':1};
for(var index in arr)
indexes.push(index);
```

same as setting arr['a']=1 etc. It's true that for..in iterates over the keys - not the values.